# I need to optimize tables and queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: info, data, link, there is a request for data:

```
select *
from data,link,info
where link.info_id = info.id and link.data_id = data.id
```

offer optimization options:
a) tables
b) request.
Queries for creating tables:

```
CREATE TABLE info (
        id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
       name varchar(255) default NULL,
        desc text default NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

CREATE TABLE data (
        id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        date date default NULL,
        value INT(11) default NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

CREATE TABLE link (
        data_id int(11) NOT NULL,
        info_id int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
 an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
 then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
 [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/),
 how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Why are you using MyISAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax:

```
select *
from data d join
     link l
     on l.data_id = d.id join
     info i
     on l.info_id = i.id;
```

Second, for this query your indexes are probably fine.  I would also recommend a primary key index on `link`:

```
CREATE TABLE link (
    data_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    info_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (data_id, info_id)
);
```

This is a good idea in general, even if it is not specific to this query.